# How to use Ajax to display K2 items in Tabs

Tags: k2, ajax

I have k2 categories, and on a category page, I need to implement the following logic:

- Loop through tabs
- Retrieve items that match category (note: I have additional categories extension in k2)
- Display items using template from a module (I have been using xperttabs)

So I am trying to use the xperttabs module, without actually have stored module instances...which I guess means copying the display code into the categories.php file?

Or is there a non-Ajax way that makes more sense? I am just trying to avoid creating 20 plus modules to display everything across my categories...

Insights appreciated! Also, I have no java experience but if I understand the process and see examples I can figure it out.

thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty vague question, but you may want to refer to this about making AJAX calls in Joomla: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component/2541#2541

Comment: or this one http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/919/load-k2-article-with-ajax

Comment: Those are all interesting links, thanks! It will take me a while to understand the mechanics of what is being described as I am new to joomla.