# How can I benefit from Joomla 3's Ajax support?

Tags: ajax

Joomla 3 begins suppporting AJAX, as a non-developer who have very limited knowledge about joomla platform and AJAX, I'm wondering if I can still take advantage of this new feature.

What I am trying to do is simple: I have a sidebar listing recent articles, and the mainbody is displaying the content of an article. I want the mainbody to display another article when I click one of the article link in the sidebar, without reloading the whole page.

Is this doable with the new AJAX feature? And what if I am using com_k2 as content provider instead of com_content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load K2 article with ajax](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/919/load-k2-article-with-ajax)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If it's code you're after, I would recommend you start trying to mock up something of your own and ask a new question with any specific coding related issues you may have ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)): **Ajax** is a group of interrelated Web development techniques used on the client-side to create asynchronous Web applications. With Ajax, web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. Data can be retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest object. Despite the name, the use of XML is not required (JSON is often used in the Ajax variant), and the requests do not need to be asynchronous.

[Joomla Ajax Interface](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface/en) is mainly oriented to developers, creating extensions, who can take advantage of a standardized API.